# SKLabelNode change number of lines

Tags: sprite-kit, sklabelnode

Is there a possibility to change the number of lines of an SKLabelNode?

Like UiLabel:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Comment: The answer is no.  Hopefully, that extended feature will be available with iOS 8.

Comment: I think there's a multi-line label extension node for sprite kit on github which splits a string into multiple labels on newlines.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible. Just set `numberOfLines` + `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`:

```
let lb = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Courier-bold")
lb.numberOfLines = 0
lb.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = size.width
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently that is not possible.

You could create your own `SKMultilineLabelNode` class if you wanted to, and as mentioned in the comments there is an extension on github.